# How do I get from lambda function to the GitLab for the first time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gitlab, cicd

I have a serverless application with more than 100 lambda functions. No version control or CI/CD has been implemented for them.  I would like to start using GitLab for setting up a CI/CD environment. I have two questions w.r.t this.

1. Is there a way where I can automate downloading them to GitLab?
2. How do I create a repository. Should I write .yml for each of those functions.

Any pointers for doing this would be very helpful.

Comment: You should probably start with a simple, single Lambda hello world project and work out how best to structure and [deploy that via GitLab](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/deploying-using-gitlab.html).

Comment: as @jarmod said, try to understand the flow first working with a single lambda/repo before trying to migrate everything. 1 - For sure, you can set up a CI to build your code and upload it to Lambda. 2 - It "depends", in most cases, it would be better to have a repo for each service, but it depends on how your services were written in the past, but if you have a chance in the future and IF it makes sense to your use-case, you can try to separate the code from each other, it will avoid a lot of things like mistakes, unnecessary changes and etc.